# How to merge two pandas dataframes on index but fill missing values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes

`df`

```
  x
0 1
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
```

`df1`

```
  y
1 1
3 1
```

And I want to merge them on the index, but still keep the indexes that aren't present in `df1`. This is my desired output

```
  x  y
0 1  0
1 1  1
2 1  0
3 1  1
4 1  0
```

I have tried merging on index, like this

```
pd.merge(df, df1s, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

But that gets rid of the index values not in `df1`. For example:

```
  x y
1 1 1
3 1 1
```

This is not what I want. I have tried both `outer` and `inner` join, to no avail. I have also tried reading through other pandas merge questions, but can't seem to figure out my specific case here. Apologies if the merge questions are redundant, but again, I cannot figure out how to merge the way I would like in this certain scenario. Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend `join` when  doing a `left merge` on `index`: You can `join` and fill nas with zero:

    `df.join(df1).fillna(0)`

Comment: Your code is missing the ``how`` parameter : ``pd.merge(df, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True, how="left").fillna(0)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to concatenate on rows and fill NaNs with 0

```
pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1).fillna(0)



  x    y
0  1  0.0
1  1  1.0
2  1  0.0
3  1  1.0
4  1  0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for any complicated merging, you can just copy the column over directly, fill the NaNs, and set the dtype. You can either do this directly, or with `pd.concat()`:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna(0).astype(int)

   x  y
0  1  0
1  1  1
2  1  0
3  1  1
4  1  0
```

Comment: How is this different from the other answer aside from the fact that you added `astype(int)`? If someone has already posted a solution, it is best not to post the same exact solution.

Comment: There were no comments posted at the time I started filling my response out, so I didn't notice that someone else had come up with a similar solution. That being said, this is still the only solution that produces the desired output asked in the original question.